# Authentication Issue with Next.js and NextAuth.js - Redirect Problem

Tags: javascript, authentication, redirect, next.js, next-auth

I'm encountering an issue with authentication in my Next.js application using NextAuth.js. Specifically, I'm facing a problem with the redirection after successful login. Here are the details of my setup:

#### **NextAuth.js Configuration (`app/api/auth/[...nextauth.js]`):**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        if (email !== "me@g.com" || password !== "123") {
          throw new Error("invalid credentials");
        }
        return {
          id: "2453",
          name: "J Smith",
          email: "me@g.com",
          role: "admin",
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt(params) {
      // console.log(params);
      //update token
      if (params.user?.role) {
        params.token.role = params.user.role;
      }
      //return final_token
      return params.token;
    },
  },
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

This is the configuration for NextAuth.js, where I specify the authentication providers and callbacks.

#### **Next.js Sign-In Page (`app/auth/login/page.jsx`):**

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
const LoginPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        email,
        password,
        redirect: false,
      });

      console.log("Response:", response);

      const isLoginSuccessful=!response.error;
      if (isLoginSuccessful) {
        router.push("/dashboard");
        console.log("Redirecting to:", "/dashboard");
      } else {
        setError("Invalid email or password");
        setTimeout(() => setError(""), 2000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("NEXT_AUTH Error:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <section>
            <form className="space-y-4 md:space-y-6">
..............................
            </form>
    </section>
  );
};
export default LoginPage;
```

This is the page where users enter their login credentials and submit the form.

**Middleware (`middleware.js`):**

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export default withAuth(
  function middleware() {
    //return NextResponse
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/dashboard", req.url))
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized(token) {
        return token?.role === 'admin';
      },
    },
  }
);

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] };
```

The middleware is used to protect certain routes, ensuring that only authenticated users with specific roles can access them.

### **Issue Description:**

When a user attempts to log in using the correct credentials, the application should redirect them to the **`/dashboard`** page. However, after submitting the login form, the application redirects to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard
```

This is not the expected behavior. Instead, it should directly redirect to `/dashboard`. The login flow works correctly, and the user is authenticated, but the redirection is incorrect.

**Steps Taken:**

I've verified the following:

- Imported **`signIn`** function from **`next-auth/react`** in the sign-in page.
- Updated the **`jwt`** callback in NextAuth.js to include the user's role in the token.

Ensured that the **`pages`** configuration in NextAuth.js correctly specifies the **`signIn`** page as **`/login`**.

- Confirmed that the middleware is correctly protecting the **`/dashboard`** route for users with the 'admin' role.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this redirection issue. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

### I encountered a similar issue with authentication in my Next.js application using NextAuth.js, specifically with redirection after successful login. Here's how I resolved it:

**NextAuth.js Configuration (app/api/auth/[...nextauth.js]):**

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
```

**Middleware (middleware.js):**

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default withAuth(
  function middleware(req) {
    //return NextResponse
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => token?.role === "admin",
    },
  }
);

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] };
```

With these changes, the redirection issue should be resolved, and your application should correctly redirect to `/dashboard` after a successful login. Make sure you have updated your NextAuth.js configuration and middleware as shown above.

I hope this helps resolve your redirection problem with NextAuth.js and Next.js!